# Connect to OneDrive using Microsoft Graph and C# not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-identity, clientcredential

I was trying to create a very simple app to connect to my OneDrive and receive a list of the various files that I have hosted on OneDrive.

This is the code:

```
string clientId = "My client Id";
string clientSecret = "The secret id value";
string tenantId = "My tennant id";
      
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

var driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();

// Display the names of all items in the list
foreach (var item in driveItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

The problem is that apparently `graphClient.Me.Drive` does not contain a `Root` definition (at least that's what Visual Studio tells me).

I am using **Microsoft.Graph v5.11** and **Azure.Identity v1.9**

Comment: Are you trying to get drives? If so, `_graphServiceClient.Me.Drives.Request()` or you need to provide a drive id to get the contents of a specific drive. `_graphServiceClient.Drives[driveId].Root.Children.Request()`

Comment: The idea was to obtain all the files in my OneDrive,, sooo i supose need to apply the second option you say? no idea, first time using Microsoft Graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now using `Microsoft.Graph v5.11` which is different from V4.x and in V5 there's no `.Request()`.

In the meantime, you are using client credential flow `new ClientSecretCredential`, so you can't use `.Me` but have to use `.Users["your_user_id"]`. Because you don't sign in first, so you have to give a user id manually. By the way, since you are using client credential flow, you have to set the scope as `var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };`. This requires you to consent [application type of api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions):

[image]
[image]

Then you code based on V5.11 should be like:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId ";
var clientId = "clientId ";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var userDriveId = await graphClient.Users["yourUserId"].Drive.GetAsync();
var driveItems = await graphClient.Drives["userDriveId"].Items["Root"].Children.GetAsync();
```

Related link: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#drive-item-paths

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is, all information i read was for previous versions.
If not abusing, how can I access a sub-sub-folder inside the root directory, once I have obtained the id of said folder?

Comment: Hi, since I don't have test result, so i can only try to query the solution. first this is the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-path), request url should be `/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children`.

Comment: code maybe `var driveItems = await graphClient.Drives["userDriveId"].Items["Root"].ItemWithPath("path").Children.GetAsync();`